# isXMLChar for 32 bit Characters

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I was using `XMLReader::isXMLChar` (Apache Xerces). But it takes only 16 bit characters (XMLCh).

```
typedef wchar_t XMLCh;
```

Do we have an alternate Apache Xerces API which takes in 32 bit characters with the same functionality?